# Not getting any data from request object using request.POST.get

Tags: python, django

I have a post view that receives an `email` and `payment_method_id`. However, when I send this data to this end_point I noticed that I am not retrieving any of the data from my request object. This is an example of what I am sending:

```
{"email":"test@gmail.com","paymentMethod_id":"pm_1LFMSIDMftTw233Mz3S9xkqE"}
```

This is my view

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_stripe_info(request):
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    payment_method_id = request.POST.get('payment_method_id')
    print('email is', email)
    print('payment method', payment_method_id)

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=email,
        payment_method=payment_method_id
    )
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={
        'message': 'Success',
        'data': {'customer_id': customer.id}
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Data using `request.data`.
`request.POST` is for form data.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects